# Como obtener con php y msqli el valor mas alto con max()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

un placer!
Voy a realizar mi primera consulta en este sitio, de ante mano, disculpas si esta mal formulada.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en donde voy a llevar un historial de precios de productos.
En una tabla ya relacionada, cargo Precio, Vendedor (obtengo de tabla vendedores), Modelo (obtengo de tabla productos) y Fecha.

Mi objetivo es lograr obtener los precios mas nuevos del producto PERO que NO SE REPITA EL VENDEDOR.

La consulta que realizo en ****phpMyAdmin** es la siguiente y me devuelve lo que quiero!

[![tabla a la cual consu][1]][1]

[![Query realizada en phpmyadminí][2]][2]

y me devuelve correctamente el precio mas alto de un producto

[![resultados en phpMyAdmin][3]][3]

Luego, realizo la misma consulta pero en un archivo PHP con la conexion mysqli y me trae valores diferentes

Podrán decirme en que me estoy equivocando en el archivo .php ?

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT MAX(precioz.precio), precioz.precio , precioz.vendedor, precioz.fecha, productos.modelo FROM precioz JOIN productos ON precioz.modelo = productos.modelo GROUP BY precioz.vendedor ORDER BY precioz.precio ASC"); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<tbody>"; echo "<td>" . $row["vendedor"] . </td>"; echo "<td>" . $row["precio"] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row["fecha"] . </td>"; echo "</tbody>"; } >
```

Espero haber explicado bien mi problema.

Muchas gracias por su aporte.

Comment: quita el max, ordena primero y después agrupa a ver que te sale.

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega el código como texto, no hay necesidad de usar para ello imágenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mostrando `precioz.precio` cuando en realidad quieres mostrar el precio máximo, mejor usa un alias para la columna agregada:

```
SELECT MAX(precioz.precio) as precio_max 
...
```

Y usa el alias sobre `$row`:

```
echo '<td>'.$row['precio_max'].'</td>';
```

Cuando haces agrupaciones, las columnas en `SELECT` que no están en `GROUP BY` y que no se les aplica  una *función de agregación* pueden traer valores aleatorios.

Comment: Funcionó tu aporte! Un pequeño, pero gran detalle. Inclui el alias y luego edite el $row en la lista! Funcionó